# How to implement a queue on a IHttpHandler in a ASP.NET Web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, queue, httphandler

I have a ASP.NET web app which have a `IHttpHandler` to process `POST` requests (basically, it will process JSON and then send back results of the processing to the client).

I would like to implement a queue system in my app so that if there is simulateneous post requests, they are not treated in parallel but one after the other.

**Questions**:

1. What is the best way implement that?
2. Where in the app should I declare the `Queue` object?
3. How can I attach a specific function (the function that will do the processing) to be executed each time an item
   is added to the queue?

I can't declare the Queue in the `Page_Load()` event because the requests won't be sent when the web page is open. I need the queue to be always waiting for incoming POST requests. If I declared the queue in the IHttpHandler, the queue will reset each time a POST request comes.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement this would be to instead use a IHttpAsyncHandler and a singleton service class. A worker thread waits for new items added to a BlockingCollection of ConcurrentQueue.  This will enable serial processing of the incoming requests. The worker thread in the service class needs to be started before the first request is processed, the start method could be called from a global Application_Start routine or by adding a PreApplicationStartMethod to the AssembleInfo.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;

namespace webgateway
{
    public class RequestHandler : IHttpAsyncHandler, IDisposable
    {


        public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
        {

            RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(cb, context, extraData);

            Service.Instance.QueueRequest(requestContext);

            return requestContext;

        }


        //Start could be called from the Global asax or by adding this attribute to the Assembly.cs 
        //[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(webgateway.RequestHandler), "Start")]
        public static void Start()
        {

            Service.Instance.Start();
        } 

        public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) {
        }
        public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) { }
        public void Dispose() { }
    }

}


public sealed class Service
{

    private static readonly Service _Instance = new Service();
    public static Service Instance
    {
        get { return _Instance; }
    }
    private Service()
    {
    }


    private static bool _running = false;

    private BlockingCollection<RequestContext> blockingQueue = new BlockingCollection<RequestContext>(new ConcurrentQueue<RequestContext>());


    public void Start()
    {
        _running = true;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(worker, null);

    }

    private void worker(object state)
    {

        RequestContext requestContext;

        while (_running)
        {

            //Block until a new item is added to the queue
            if (blockingQueue.TryTake(out requestContext, 10000))
            {

                //You could delegate the work to another function , class , library or process inline here... 

                //Simulate a random delay 
                Thread.Sleep((new Random()).Next(1000, 5000));


                //Make sure the client is connected before sending the response 
                if (requestContext.HttpContext.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    requestContext.HttpContext.Response.BufferOutput = false;
                    requestContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(requestContext.HttpContext.Request["echo"]);
                    requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
                    requestContext.CompleteCall();
                }

            }

        }

    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _running = false;
    }

    public void QueueRequest(RequestContext requestContext)
    {

        if (!blockingQueue.TryAdd(requestContext))
        {
            //handle error 
        }
    }

}

public class RequestContext : IAsyncResult
{

    private ManualResetEvent _event;
    private object _lock = new Object();
    private AsyncCallback _callback;
    private HttpContext _httpContext;
    private bool _completed;
    private bool _completedSynchronously;
    private object _state;

    public RequestContext(AsyncCallback cb, HttpContext hc, object state)
    {
        _callback = cb;
        _httpContext = hc;
        _completedSynchronously = false;
        _completed = false;
        _state = state;
    }

    public HttpContext HttpContext
    {
        get { return _httpContext; }
    }

    public void CompleteCall()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _completed = true;
            if (_event != null)
            {
                _event.Set();
            }
        }

        _callback?.Invoke(this);
    }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return _completed; }
    }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously
    {
        get { return _completedSynchronously; }
    }

    public object AsyncState
    {
        get { return _state; }
    }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {

                if (_event == null)
                {
                    _event = new ManualResetEvent(IsCompleted);
                }
                return _event;
            }
        }
    }

}
```